# MySQL JOIN problems with two child tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm learning MySQL JOINs now and one thing I want to know is how to JOIN two child tables with one father table.

In this case, the query is this:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL';

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `test` ;

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

USE `test`;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`objetos` (
  `idobjetos` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `modelo` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `descricao` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `token_dono` VARCHAR(41) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idobjetos`, `token_dono`) ,
  INDEX `token_dono` (`token_dono` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`empresas` (
  `idempresa` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `cnpj` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `telefone` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `token` VARCHAR(41) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idempresa`, `token`) ,
  INDEX `token_empresa` (`token` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `cnpj_UNIQUE` (`cnpj` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `telefone_UNIQUE` (`telefone` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `token_empresa`
    FOREIGN KEY (`token` )
    REFERENCES `test`.`objetos` (`token_dono` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`civis` (
  `idcivil` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `token` VARCHAR(41) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcivil`, `token`) ,
  INDEX `token_civil` (`token` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `cpf_UNIQUE` (`cpf` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `token_civil`
    FOREIGN KEY (`token` )
    REFERENCES `test`.`objetos` (`token_dono` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`an_users` (
  `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `usuario` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `senha` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `cod_usuario` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `cod_usuario`) ,
  INDEX `cod_usuario_fk` (`cod_usuario` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `cod_usuario_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cod_usuario` )
    REFERENCES `test`.`empresas` (`idempresa` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

And I've inserted these values:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`objetos` VALUES (NULL, 'Cadeira XTT', 'Quê?', SHA1(CONCAT(3913123612,'one@gmail.com')));
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`objetos` VALUES (NULL, 'Mesa TTX', 'Hein?', SHA1(CONCAT(4313123612,'two@gmail.com')));
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`objetos` VALUES (NULL, 'Prédio TT', 'Hein?', SHA1(CONCAT(73358847000116,'buzz@gmail.com')));

INSERT INTO `mydb`.`civis` VALUES (NULL, 'One', 3913123612, 'one@gmail.com', SHA1(CONCAT(3913123612,'one@gmail.com')));
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`civis` VALUES (NULL, 'Two', 4313123612, 'two@gmail.com', SHA1(CONCAT(4313123612,'two@gmail.com')));

INSERT INTO `mydb`.`empresas` VALUES(NULL, 'Buzz', 73358847000116, 'buzz@gmail.com', 33270743, SHA1(CONCAT(73358847000116,'buzz@gmail.com')));
```

But there are some problems when I want to retrieve the recorded data. The NATURAL JOIN doesn't work as the expected, taking only the rows with the same token and I can't to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM objetos 

JOIN civis 
ON(objetos.token_dono = civis.token) 

JOIN empresas 
ON(objetos.token_dono = empresas.token)
```

To list all "objetos" from database with correct informations. But as I've tested it not work.

If someone can give me a light with these problems I'll be grateful.

Comment: What you probably want is a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Can you select everything from the tables to make sure you inserted the values in the right order ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN has worked but when I pass it to PHP how I will know which of "nome" column I have to take? Because when I did the query the columns "nome" didn't mix and then I've two columns with the same label.

Comment: And yes, I can select everything from each table and I can do a SELECT * FROM objeto JOIN civis, for example.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want your results to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are experiencing is that the unqualified `JOIN` is actually interpreted as `INNER JOIN` see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) for more details.

So when you run your query the row not containing a matching `token` from `objetos` is dropped and then since no token from `civis` match `token` from `empresas` all rows are dropped.

So from what I gather you are trying to do you will actually need to do a `LEFT JOIN` if you want to get all columns from all tables or separate this one query into to like so:

```
SELECT * FROM objetos o JOIN civis c ON (o.token_dono = c.token);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM objetos o JOIN empresas e ON (o.token_dono = e.token);
```

Comment: I used it and UNION to make what I want. Thank you people.